# PHP - Inserting into database issues

Tags: php, database

I've been stuck on this one portion of my coding for a while with changes either getting a syntax error or a message that says it's an unknown column. I've tried with single quotes and without and I think I tried double quotes before and got nothing. I'm pretty sure the problem is with the query part but I'm not sure at this point.

```
include_once "library.php";
connectdatabase();

if (isset($_COOKIE['bunny_id'])) {
    $poster = $_COOKIE['bunny_id'];
} else {
    echo "Sorry, you need to login or sign up before you can post :C";
}

if (!empty($_POST['topic_name'])) {
    $topic_name = "'" . addslashes($_POST['topic_name']) . "'";
} else {
    $topic_name = 'NULL';
    echo "Topic field is not filled :c \n";
    exit;
}

if (!empty($_POST['post_content'])) {
    $post_content = "'" . addslashes($_POST['post_content']) . "'";
} else {
    $post_content = 'NULL';
    echo "Post content is not filled :c \n";
    exit;
}

$query  = "INSERT INTO posts(messages_poster, messages_topic, messages_content) VALUES('$poster', '$topic_name', '$post_content')";
$query2 = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_num_rows($query2) == 1) {
    echo "Topic has been created~";
    exit;
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there's been an error :c";
}
```

EDIT: I managed to solve the problem. The problem was related to adding single quotes to '$topic_name' and '$post_content' (smaller problem also involved using mysql_num_rows instead of mysql_affected_rows) after already adding quotes in previous parts of the code. It runs fine now~

Comment: Try again, I edited the code in your question and removed the most obvious problems.

Comment: use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string) instead of `addslashes()`, ...On the top use **prepared statements**,

Comment: Show us your error. Unknown column means your table column name is incorrect.

Comment: Using prepared statements is the way to make it easier and less error-prone to get data into your database. The best approach would be using PDO. http://bobby-tables.com/php.html has examples.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO posts(messages_poster, messages_topic, messages_content) VALUES('$poster', '$topic_name', '$post_content')";
    $query2=mysql_query($query);

         if(mysql_num_rows($query2) == 1) {

        echo "Topic has been created~";
    exit; 
    } else { 
        echo "Sorry, there's been an error :c";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be sure that your three column `(messages_poster, messages_topic, messages_content)` contains in your table `posts`.
Also check with the query `mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())` to make sure what is the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
   include_once "library.php";`
  connectdatabase();`
  $poster = '';
 if(isset($_COOKIE['bunny_id'])){
        $poster= $_COOKIE['bunny_id'];
        } 
         else {
            echo "Sorry, you need to login or sign up before you can post :C";
        } 
  $topic_name = '';
  if (!empty($_POST['topic_name'])){
     $topic_name = "'". addslashes($_POST['topic_name']) . "'";
} else {
    $topic_name = 'NULL';   
    echo "Topic field is not filled :c \n";
    exit;
}   
$post_content = '';
    if (!empty($_POST['post_content'] )) { 
    $post_content = "'". addslashes ( $_POST['post_content'] ) . "'";
} else {
    $post_content = 'NULL'; 
    echo "Post content is not filled :c \n" ;
    exit;
} 

        $query = "INSERT INTO posts(messages_poster, messages_topic, messages_content) VALUES('$poster', '$topic_name', '$post_content')";
        $query2=mysql_query($query);

             if(mysql_num_rows($query2) == 1) {

            echo "Topic has been created~";
        exit; 
         } else { 
            echo "Sorry, there's been an error :c";
            }
```

The issue could be that you are not getting these values '$poster', '$topic_name', '$post_content' as they are locally defined in your code.

Show us your error. Unknown column means your table column name is incorrect.

Comment: My current error debugging code looks like this:  `if ( mysql_errno() == 0 ) {
  echo "Looks good!";
  } else {
  echo "<p>Oh noes! Somethings wrong!</p>\n";
  echo "Its this: " .mysql_error(). "</p>\n";
  }`
The message I'm getting so far (even with fixes) is Its this: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Testing 3'', ''This is the testing that never ennds...'')' at line 1

Comment: try this 'echo $query  die();' after your query. It will print the query then run it and check the error. There is some syntax error in your query.

Answer (score 0):

```
 include_once "library.php";`
  connectdatabase();`

 if(isset($_COOKIE['bunny_id'])){
        $poster= $_COOKIE['bunny_id'];
        } 
         else {
            echo "Sorry, you need to login or sign up before you can post :C";
        } 

  if (!empty($_POST['topic_name'])){
     $topic_name =  addslashes($_POST['topic_name']); // we no need to concat string
} else {
    $topic_name = '';   
    echo "Topic field is not filled :c \n";
    exit;
}   

    if (!empty($_POST['post_content'] )) { 
    $post_content = addslashes ( $_POST['post_content'] ) ;
} else {
    $post_content = ''; 
    echo "Post content is not filled :c \n" ;
    exit;
} 

        `$query = "INSERT INTO posts (messages_poster, messages_topic, messages_content) VALUES('$poster', '$topic_name', '$post_content')";
        $query2=mysql_query($query) or die("could not inserted");`
         $lastid = mysql_insert_id();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a DBMS at hand to test it, but a first look at the code makes me feel the error might be in trying to build/construct the query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO posts(messages_poster, messages_topic, messages_content) VALUES('$poster', '$topic_name', '$post_content')";
```

Please note that you will want to pass the query to another subroutine (where it will be handled i.e. submitted to DBMS) as below:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO posts(messages_poster, messages_topic, messages_content) VALUES( 'val1',  'val2', 'val3')"; so the trick is in trying to translate $poster -> 'val1';
$topic_name -> 'val2'
$post_content-> 'val3'
```